# Is there a cleaner way to give dictionary-like access to a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a chunk class and I want it to contain references(represented by a int identifier) to objects that are occupying certain coordinates in the chunk. Since many objects don't have collisions, the same position may be occupied by multiple objects. The chunks have 2 dimensions (x,y). Here is what I was thinking to achieve this:

```
public class Chunk{

public List<int>[] objPresence;

}
```

This would make an array of lists( in which size = chunksizeX * chunksizeY) where the index would be the flattened x,y coordinates, and the list would contain all objects on that position. ( each int in the list would be my identifier of a given object )

So to find what objects are currently in a given position I would do:

```
listOfObjectsOnPosition = objPresence[ flattenIndex(x,y) ];
```

So far so good, but now if I want to check if one specific object is in a certain position I have to iterate through the list, and I would like to be able to have O(1) access on this.

So here is the alternative using dictionary:

```
public class Chunk{

public Dictionary<int,byte>[] objPresence;

}
```

and for access, to find a certain object:

```
objPresence[ flattenIndex(x,y) ].ContainsKey(objToSearch)
```

I can also iterate through the dictionary keys if I just want to get all objects in the position.

However in this method since I am using Dictionary, and the int key is the identifier for the object, the byte value on the dictionary is wasting memory since i dont need that value for anything.

Is there a way to implement what I have here without that wasted byte, or is there another, better way to do this altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you not just looking for a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you mean `HashSet<int>[]`, right?

Comment: thank you I was not aware of the existence of hashset, can you submit it as an answer please